# Custom keyValue type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have defined an custom type like

```
export type keyValuePairType = { text: string, value: string | keyValuePairType[] };
```

now I am using it like,

```
testInput: KeyValuePair[] = [
            { text: 'Name', value: 'nameVal' },
            { text: 'age', value: 'ageVal' },
            {
                text: 'Status', value:[
                    { text: 'Job', value: 'active' },
                ]
            }];
```

but I am getting value in "status" object as it is expecting "string" as a value only.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It runs okay (in 3.7 with its improved recursive types): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=18&pln=3&pc=30#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDWxEDUCGAbAV2AAUcBLKAFWVQF44BvBUGALjgGcYoyA7AcwA0cAG74i7LjwFwAPuky5CJclRoBtALpwAvgG4AsAChjAYwi8uzLgEleYAmwXZxKitRRa49dcbj+AwP8mGBZ2AHIAORwAW2Bw4TFlCN5Y4CVw3UE-INyQsLhwnH54xNcI4vT8TJ1so1y8nIaG0JAncIBlGBwYAg4E0XLfeubR4OY2iIApCAAjAaSJQpxTGDIReKymsYDNbeadTT0gA

Comment: `keyValuePairType !== KeyValuePair`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks. I renamed the type later at one place and could not catch it where I was using. you nailed it. Thank You.